# How can I search terminal output?

Tags: grep, git, search, output

Say I type `git help` to learn about the merge command. I don't want to read all the output just the lines that contain merge and their surrounding lines.

I thought this would be a common question but couldn't find it. I think grep can be used somehow to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `grep` can do something like this: its `-C` option will show the context of a match. Thus

```
git help | grep -C2 merge
```

will show lines containing “merge”, with two lines of context above and below.

I find it more convenient to use `less`:

```
git help | less
```

then search using <kbd>/</kbd>.

```
git help
```

won’t tell you much though, you’ll need

```
git help merge
```

which will open the relevant manpage for you.

Some terminal emulators also allow searching after the fact; for example, GNOME Terminal has a Search menu, and you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to start a search.